# How to get 2d array from multiple line String?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Sorry for my noob question..
I have String with multpile lines

String is like this:

```
1   kave    Topli napitci   7
2   sokovi  Sokovi  12
3   pive    Pive    14
4   žestice     Domaæa Žestoka P    16
7   ostalo  Hrana   50
8   vino    Vino    33
9   6   Strana Žestoka P    34
```

What i want to get 2d array for every word.

I do something like this:

```
String[] lines =string.split(System.lineSeparator());

String[] parts =  string[0].split("\t");
String[] parts1 = string[1].split("\t");
String[] parts2 = string[2].split("\t"); ....
```

Please help how to do this in 2d array.

Comment: Use a for loop to navigate the `lines` array.

Comment: Can you show some code output please mister?

Comment: @NikolaBozic is this string in a file? Or is it assigned to a variable in your program?

Comment: Its a variable in program , but parsed from file.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String[]> lines = Arrays.stream(string.split(System.lineSeparator())).map(line -> line.split("\t")).collect(Collectors.toList());
lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()][]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to assign the values directly to the array (but use ArrayList) while parsing from the file with something like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> array = new ArrayList<String[]>;

while (file.hasNextLine()) {
   String str = file.nextLine();
   String[] strArr = str.split("\t");
   array.add(strArr);
}
```

This should give you an ArrayList filled with String Arrays that are split at the `"\t"` delimeter.

Comment: Yeah but this String is not complete file, the complete file has many more lines, this string is cut from wholw file.